# Snappy: How can I snappy compress byte buffer type?

Tags: java, compression, snappy

In my Java code, I have data of type `java.nio.ByteBuffer`. I have to snappy compress this. Using `Snappy.compress()` by importing `org.xerial.snappy.Snappy;` throws an error.

```
Snappy.compress(DataUtility.parseValue(record.valueSchema(), record.value())))
```

Do I need to convert this to another type before compressing or do I have to use a different compression method?

Thank you!

Comment: "throws an error" - What error?

Comment: Take a look at `Snappy.compress(ByteBuffer uncompressed, ByteBuffer compressed)`.

Comment: The error is `Cannot resolve method 'compress(java.nio.ByteBuffer)'`

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot resolve method 'compress(java.nio.ByteBuffer)'

That's because there is no method which accepts a `ByteBuffer` for input and returns a `byte[]`.

Your options:

- Use [`int compress(java.nio.ByteBuffer uncompressed, java.nio.ByteBufferc ompressed)`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/1.1.4/org/xerial/snappy/Snappy.html#compress-java.nio.ByteBuffer-java.nio.ByteBuffer-), providing a `ByteBuffer` with input data and another one to receive the compressed data, or
- Get the input data into a `byte[]` first then use it as input to `compress(byte[])`:

.

```
byte[] inputBytes = new byte[inputBBuffer.remaining()];
inputBBuffer.get(inputBytes);

byte[] output = compress(inputBytes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried the second method and it threw me an IOException. The first method requires the second parameter `ByteBuffer` to have a fixed size while declaring it. Since I won't know the size of the compressed output, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Not quite sure about how Snappy really works, but you could try and initialize the output buffer to at least the same size of the input.